# Gate Driver topology for Buck boost Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, gate-driving, buck-boost

I am implementing inverting Buck-Boost Converter in hardware as shown in the picture attached. The output of this converter is negative. so I will have an issue with its gate driver. The gate driver of high side MOSFET will face negative voltages at the source. so the gate driver that I have used IR2110 will not handle the negative voltage. Can you please suggest me the gate driver topology spacillay for inverting buck-boost converter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwaBFe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is essentially a buck supply that's being lied to about where ground is.